# SharePoint hosted app - settings link href "#"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

Detailed question here,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359138/updating-angular-1-2-10-to-latest-with-a-minor-bug-overriding-a-href-third-pa

Issue,

```
< a tabindex = "0"
title = "Settings"
class = "ms-core-menu-root"
href = "#"
onclick = "SP.UI.Controls.Navigation.showSettingsLink('chromeControl','2px')" > < span class = "ms-siteactions-imgspan" > < img id = "chromeControl_topheader_settingsimg"
src = "https://asdasd.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev1/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=1441216769603&amp;resource=spcommon"
alt = "Settings"
style = "border:none;display:inline-block;"
title = "Settings"
class = "ms-core-menu-buttonIcon" > < /span>
<span tabindex="0" style="padding-top:4px;display:none" class="ms-core-menu-root">Settings</span > < /a>
```

I want to override `href = "#"`

no option found here - http://chadschroeder.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-chrome-control.html

I am using this,

```
    // create the sharepoint chrome control
    var nav = new SP.UI.Controls.Navigation("chrome_ctrl_container", spChromeControlData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around but is there any way better ?

```
       //fix issues with chrome ctrl
        $('body').on('click', '.ms-core-menu-root', function () {
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:;")
        });
```